# Get-ADUser Filter Parameter with msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to filter some conditions with Get-ADUser to get Users, since I have input some value same as UserPrincipalName into msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20 **(e.g. Email address)**, when I run this code it didn't show any error with it but not working, how to solve this problem, please kindly help

Thanks

```
$msDS = "msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20"  
get-aduser -filter {(Enabled -eq $true) -and (UserPrincipalName -eq '$msDS')} -SearchBase 'OU="",OU="",OU="" ,DC=""' -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress,"msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20",UserPrincipalName | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes surrounding the variable: `$msDS` and see if that works for ya.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala  After remove the quotes shows no error but still not working. Thanks for your advice !

Comment: Maybe change: `UserPrincipalName -eq '$msDS'` to this: `UserPrincipalName -match $msDS` or, you can use the `-Like` operator instead.

Comment: A UPN consists of a UPN prefix (the user account name) and a UPN suffix (a DNS domain name). The prefix joins the suffix using the "@" symbol. Your query will never return any result because `msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20` is not a valid UPN.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Not working. Thanks.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for your reply, I wonder is there any  other way to check both are the same string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LDAP`'s query filter syntax does not support arbitrary comparison across multiple attributes the way you wish (although that would have been cool!) - you'll want to query all possible users and filter them client-side with PowerShell:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase 'OU="",OU="",OU="" ,DC=""' -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress,"msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20",UserPrincipalName | Where-Object {
    $_.passwordexpired -eq $false -and $_.'msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute20' -eq $_.UserPrincipalName
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mathias R. Jessen,
Thanks for your reply, your advice on using $_. ,
helps me solve the problem.

Comment: @HerryHuang That's great! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left